# SDDM ignores custom configuration (/etc/sddm.conf)

Tags: lockscreen, display-manager, kde-plasma, fedora-28

I've been trying to configure a new theme for SDDM but whatever the changes I do the settings window or manually in /etc/sddm.conf, the embedded default greeter is still the one I get when booting, and the default lock-screen is still the one I get after sleep. I'm on Fedora 28, KDE 5.13.5, kernel 4.19, trying to set [Chili](https://github.com/MarianArlt/kde-plasma-chili) as my lockscreen and greeter. Installed it via KDE's SDDM settings GUI, checked the install dir and everything's where it should be. Here is my /etc/sddm.conf :

```
       │ File: sddm.conf
       │________________________
   1   │ [Autologin]
   2   │ Relogin=false
   3   │ Session=plasma.desktop
   4   │ User=renard
   5   │ 
   6   │ [General]
   7   │ Numlock=on
   8   │ HaltCommand=
   9   │ RebootCommand=
  10   │ 
  11   │ [Theme]
  12   │ Current=plasma-chili
  13   │ CursorTheme=Adwaita
  14   │ 
  15   │ [Users]
  16   │ MaximumUid=65000
  17   │ MinimumUid=1000
```

Also the theme works just fine when using `sddm-greeter --test-mode --theme /usr/share/sddm/themes/plasma-chili/`. I can't acces /var/lib/ssdm which seems normal, and I have no sddm.conf.d folder anywhere. Even more puzzling is that it's an issue I've read a bit about before coming here, and I've seen people back from 2014 having the same problems, but I couldn't find a fix anywhere.

Comment: Well this question doesn't seem to be popular. I'll post an answer if I ever find one. Besides feel free to give yours if you find a solution, any time, really.

Answer (score 3):

It actually does not ignore it - or rather: it is complicated.

I had the same problem, so I checked how it works:

In the sddm source file `daemon/PowerManager.cpp` there are several backends listed, how pushing the shutdown or the restart button should be handled, and only one of them uses the `HaltCommand` from `/etc/sddm.conf`.

For shutdown/HaltCommand, the relevant function is powerOff().

So, what does powerOff() actually do?

```
/************************************************/
/* POWER MANAGER BACKEND                        */
/************************************************/
    virtual void powerOff() const = 0;
/**********************************************/
/* UPOWER BACKEND                             */
/**********************************************/
// comment from me: some reference to org.freedesktop.UPower"
    void powerOff() const {
        QProcess::execute(mainConfig.HaltCommand.get());   // <---------------
    }
/**********************************************/
/* LOGIN1 && ConsoleKit2 BACKEND              */
/**********************************************/
    void powerOff() const {
        m_interface->call(QStringLiteral("PowerOff"), true);
    }
/**********************************************/
/* POWER MANAGER                              */
/**********************************************/
void PowerManager::powerOff() const {
    if (daemonApp->testing())
        return;

    for (PowerManagerBackend *backend: m_backends) {
        if (backend->capabilities() & Capability::PowerOff) {
            backend->powerOff();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `sddm.conf` is read into `mainConfig`, so `mainConfig.HaltCommand` holds that command from `/etc/sddm.conf`, which you are so eager to have executed when you press the button on the screen.

I don't know, if the `HaltCommand` in `/etc/fstab` is a feature in progress, which will eventually get to be implemented in every backend, or the documentation is broken, as it fails to mention that this only will ever work with a specific backend...

I did not go over the whole code, so it is even possible that the intention is that if a HaltCommand is presented in sddm.conf, then regardless of backend, that command should be executed, only they did not get around to implement it, or they forgot it over time.

I am using Debian Stretch with systemd, so I am pretty sure, I have the LOGIN1 && ConsoleKit2 backend. Wile this is not ideal, at least I now know that I am not messing up the config, rather, what I wanted cannot be done with sddm tweaking...

NOTE: I was using the sddm-0.14.0 code from the Debian sources for my investigation. I checked the latest sources at

[src/daemon/PowerManager.cpp](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/blob/develop/src/daemon/PowerManager.cpp)

And it seems, this code did not change.

Although, I did not check it (not even sure, how to do it), it seems, if you switch to `UPower` backend, you will get the `HaltCommand` functionality.

Also, it seems to me, a couple of `if`-s in all the backends would do the trick of using the `HaltCommand`, whenever it is changed from the default by the user.

---

While I am at it, checked what happens to the `Current` configuration item in the latest source. It seems, it should work:

Here is the [theme] config, as the code sees it:

[src/common/Configuration.h](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/blob/develop/src/common/Configuration.h)

```
    Section(Theme,
        Entry(ThemeDir,            QString,     _S(DATA_INSTALL_DIR "/themes"),             _S("Theme directory path"));
        Entry(Current,             QString,     _S(""),                                     _S("Current theme name"));
        Entry(FacesDir,            QString,     _S(DATA_INSTALL_DIR "/faces"),              _S("Global directory for user avatars\n"
                                                                                               "The files should be named <username>.face.icon"));
        Entry(CursorTheme,         QString,     QString(),                                  _S("Cursor theme used in the greeter"));
        Entry(EnableAvatars,       bool,        true,                                       _S("Enable display of custom user avatars"));
        Entry(DisableAvatarsThreshold,int,      7,                                          _S("Number of users to use as threshold\n"
                                                                                               "above which avatars are disabled\n"
                                                                                               "unless explicitly enabled with EnableAvatars"));
    );
```

This is the part, where the "Current" theme is actually gets parsed and checked, it seems, it should give you a warning - maybe in /var/log/sddm.log - if it does not find it:

[src/daemon/Display.cpp](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/blob/develop/src/daemon/Display.cpp)

```
QString Display::findGreeterTheme() const {
    QString themeName = mainConfig.Theme.Current.get();

    // an unconfigured theme means the user wants to load the
    // default theme from the resources
    if (themeName.isEmpty())
        return QString();

    QDir dir(mainConfig.Theme.ThemeDir.get());

    // return the default theme if it exists
    if (dir.exists(themeName))
        return dir.absoluteFilePath(themeName);

    // otherwise use the embedded theme
    qWarning() << "The configured theme" << themeName << "doesn't exist, using the embedded theme instead";
    return QString();
}
```

I am a bit lost here, but it seems, IF the theme is found on the path, then it looks for the theme configuration files, either in the `themePath/metadata.desktop`, or somehow you can configure a custom named theme configuration file. I think `themePath` is `[theme] ThemeDir` in `sddm.conf`.

[src/daemon/Greeter.cpp](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/blob/develop/src/daemon/Greeter.cpp)

```
void Greeter::setTheme(const QString &theme) {
    m_themePath = theme;

    if (theme.isEmpty()) {
        m_metadata->setTo(QString());
        m_themeConfig->setTo(QString());
    } else {
        const QString path = QStringLiteral("%1/metadata.desktop").arg(m_themePath);
        m_metadata->setTo(path);

        QString configFile = QStringLiteral("%1/%2").arg(m_themePath).arg(m_metadata->configFile());
        m_themeConfig->setTo(configFile);
    }
}
```

All-in-all, you could try look into (from problem-solving to work-around):

1. is your theme on the path? try giving the absolute path! check `/var/log/sddm.log` and also `/var/log/syslog` for this `"The configured theme" << themeName << "doesn't exist, using the embedded theme instead"` error message!
2. try adding `themeDir`
3. does your theme have a `metadata.desktop` file? if not, try to rename/symlink a file that seems like it could be the theme's version of it
4. `sddm --example-config` prints your current config; if it pops up a `[theme] Current`, copy/symlink your theme in that location (maybe backup the original), and see what happens

NOTE: I did not see any more conditions in the code for using theme other than "does this file exists?" - which does not mean they are not there.  However, I did see that the theme is used to create user-icons, user-face, whatever, so it possible that it fails due to some missing resources down the road - I doubt this is the case, but it is possible.

While it is not a full answer, I already looked at the code, so I gave it a go, I hope I turned up something you can use to solve the problem!

Comment: This is interesting but this is not what my problem is. The HaltCommand et RebootCommand lines were there before I write in anything. My problem is about the greeter and lockscreen. To this day, I haven't found a way to get rid of this butt-ugly XFCE default greeter nor even changing my lockscreen to Chili's.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I mainly answered to "does this even read my config?" - which drove me crazy for about a day. 

Anyway, I did a quick check, what is happening with the theme, I added it to my
answer.